# Exec(file.py) with arguments not working

Tags: php, python, html

i have to create a website to compare two pictures given by the user.
I've created the pyhton file to compare this two files ( using sys.argv in python ) but i don't know how can I put arguments for my python prog.

I've tried with &argv1 and &argv2 and put it row in:

```
[...]
&argv1 = "image.jpg"
&argv2 = "image2.jpg"
   $command = escapeshellcmd('Diff1.py');
    $output = shell_exec($command);
        exec ('Diff1.py' &argv1 &argv2);

    echo '<p><img src="resultat.jpg" alt="icon"/></p>';
 //The Python prog return a file named resultat.jpg and i have to show it
```

but it didn't works.

So how could I do ?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I have no idea about the `exec` command in PHP, but does `Diff`.py` have execution permission? Have you tried calling it as `python ./Diff1.py`?

Comment: Yes but no way ..

Answer (score 0):

You missed here to mention program (`python`)that will execute your .py file. Also you will need to more arguments, output(array) and error(int).

```
exec ('python Diff1.py ' . $argv1 . ' ' .$argv2, $output, $error);
```

In case you are using windows, make sure that python is set in `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: I don't really understand the PATH environment variable, i'm running the python file on a server ( the main goal of this work is to compare on a website two pictures )

Comment: He's saying that if the server is a Windows server you should make sure that python is added to the `path` system environment variable. If you're using a Linux server then nevermind.

Comment: Sorry for being late, we're on a Linux server so the path isn't needed..